# calculate percentage of each row for a specific column in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

please i am trying to get the percentage of a column called totalvotes in the table called candidates for each row and also show the sum total of all the  column totalvotes. if their positions are the same. Now what i have achieved is that i am able to get both SUM TOTAL and percentage but the problem now is the
**the first row that is displayed in my table on the page is always 100% which i is not to be so**
please this is my code

```
    <?php


                        $counter=0;
$sql = mysqli_query($ret, "SELECT * From candidates WHERE position_id='$position_id'

ORDER BY candidates.position_id DESC,candidates.totalvotes DESC");
$row = mysqli_num_rows($sql);
$arr = array($row);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
//echo "". $row['campus_id'] ;
$total += $row['totalvotes'];
$perc =$row['totalvotes']*'100'/$total ; 

$counter++;
                     echo   "<tr class='odd pointer'>" ;




                     echo   "<td class='a-center '>";


                     echo   "<input type='checkbox' class='flat' name='table_records'>";


                     echo   " </td>" ;
                     echo   " <td >". $row['candidate_id']."</td>";
                     echo  " <td >". $row['fullname']."</td>";
                     echo  " <td >". $row['sex']."</td>";
                     echo   "</td>" ;
                     echo   " <td >". $row['totalvotes']."</td>";
                      echo   " <td >".$perc."%</td>";
                     echo   "";
                     echo   " </td>";
                     echo   "</tr>";

                         }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it your answer let me know:

```
<?php
$counter=0;

$sql = mysqli_query($ret, "SELECT * From candidates WHERE position_id='$position_id' ORDER BY candidates.position_id DESC, candidates.totalvotes DESC");
$row = mysqli_num_rows($sql);
$arr = array($row);

$totalvotes = 0;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
    $totalvotes += $row['totalvotes'];
}

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
    //echo "". $row['campus_id'] ;

    $perc = ($row['totalvotes']*'100'/$total); 

    echo   "<tr class='odd pointer'>" ;

    echo   "<td class='a-center '><input type='checkbox' class='flat' name='table_records'></td>" ;

    echo   "<td>". $row['candidate_id']."</td>";
    echo  " <td>". $row['fullname']."</td>";
    echo  " <td>". $row['sex']."</td>";

    echo   " <td>". $row['totalvotes']."</td>";
    echo   " <td>".$perc."%</td>";

    echo   "</tr>";

    $counter++;
}
?>
```

Comment: this is  my ork it works perfect except that the first row will always show 100%